# HTML + Javascript Database Small Website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, air, adobe

I am trying to create an Adobe Air Application, or making basic Mobile Apps with the new Adobe Dreamweaver 5.5 for mobile Apps, that connects to my server online to grab content.
I have never created a database 'product' using just HTML + Javascript to display.

IE: An Address Book.

```
[[ Show list of contacts ]]
<a href="details.php?contactId=123">John Doe</a>  <<-- This would then take you to the contact details
```

But with HTML + JS you can't really replicate that process.

I currently have this setup to pull data from the server.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {   
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://www.domain.ca/classes/brain.php?a=select',
        crossDomain: true,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',           
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

            $("#taskList").empty();
            $("#tasksTemplate").tmpl(data).appendTo("#taskList");

        },

        error: function(responseText) {
            alert('Error: '+ responseText.toString());  
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

So this will display my content on the page... 
BUT how do I link the 2 pages together... such as in the address book?

```
<a href="details.html">John Doe</a>
```

Any help would be appreciated....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a href="#" class="myLink">John Doe</a>
```

and

```
$('.myLink').live('click', function() {
    // ajax stuff
});
```